# Mysql DB w/Street Addresses - I want to Sort by Name then Number?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having fits with writing either php or mysql for this.  I have one field that has a street address like "12-A Test Drive"  ... I'd like to sort the entire results by the address name, then by the street number.  I've figured out how to sort by address name, but can't quite get the street number right.

Here is my mysql command so far:

```
SELECT address from property_details ORDER BY SUBSTR(LTRIM(address), LOCATE(' ',LTRIM(address)))

308 Berry Street, 
317 Berry Street, 
803 E. California, 
2046 Lost Thistle Way, 
2000 Lost Thistle Way, 
2019 Lost Thistle Way, 
14 Perry Dr, 
5 Perry Dr, 
10224 Stone Plaza, 
211 Sumney Ave, 
209 Sumney Ave, 
35-B Wicket, 
35-A Wicket, 
317-B Wicket, 
53 Wicket
```

When I want it to show like this:

```
308 Berry Street, 
317 Berry Street, 
803 E. California, 
2000 Lost Thistle Way, 
2019 Lost Thistle Way, 
2046 Lost Thistle Way, 
5 Perry Dr, 
14 Perry Dr, 
10224 Stone Plaza, 
209 Sumney Ave, 
211 Sumney Ave, 
35-A Wicket, 
35-B Wicket, 
53 Wicket, 
317 Wicket
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to change your database schema to store property number, name and street separately...

Comment: Because the site has so many places referencing it, I'd like to try and solve this by mysql command.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep using the `SUBSTR` and `LOCATE` functions you're already using. You can `ORDER` by multiple things, but will need to change strings to numbers if you want numerical order. This requires pulling out a hyphen character if present. This won't work if you have addresses like "123A Any Street".

```
SELECT
  address,
  CONVERT (
    IF (LOCATE('-', address),
      SUBSTR(TRIM(address), 1, LOCATE('-',TRIM(address)) - 1),
      SUBSTR(TRIM(address), 1, LOCATE(' ',TRIM(address)) - 1)
    ), UNSIGNED
  ) AS number,
  SUBSTR(TRIM(address), LOCATE(' ',TRIM(address))) AS street
FROM property_details
ORDER BY street, number;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1775/4

Comment: Thank you for your help!  The list looks good except for the last several.  Here is the ordering of what happens at the end of the list:

33-B Wicket, 
34-A Wicket, 
34-B Wicket, 
60-B Wicket, 
61-A Wicket, 
61-B Wicket, 
64-B Wicket, 
32-B Wicket, 
63-1A Wicket, 
65-A Wicket, 
65-B Wicket, 
63-1B Wicket,  
293A Wicket, 
293B Wicket, 
63-2A Wicket,   
295A Wicket, 
63-2B Wicket, 
295B Wicket,       
297B Wicket,          
297A Wicket          

How could it be written to get everything ordering properly?

Comment: It's been edited, give that a try. And perhaps whoever doesn't know what the downvote button is for can explain themselves.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll give it a try.  I do have some 123A Any Street types as well as 123-A any streets.  Is that impossible to solve?

Comment: Just another IF statement inside the existing one probably doing a REGEXP check for an all-numeric value, and trimming as necessary. It would get quite complicated.

Comment: If this was helpful, please upvote; if it solved your problem please mark as accepted. Since someone downvoted it, I will delete it shortly if it's not helpful. Thanks.